# Rails 7: Compiling assets with different folder structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typescript

I am having a problem with my rails app. Today I upgraded from Rails 6 to Rails 7. In Rails 7 webpacker is kinda removed, so I am now using ESBuild. In my project I have TypeScript and SASS files. To compile these assets I am running the following script:

```
import esbuild from "esbuild";
import { sassPlugin } from "esbuild-sass-plugin";
import postcss from 'postcss';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';

// Generate CSS/JS Builds
esbuild
    .build({
        entryPoints: ['app/assets/scss/app.scss', 'app/assets/ts/app.ts'],
        outdir: "dist",
        bundle: true,
        metafile: true,
        plugins: [
            sassPlugin({
                async transform(source) {
                    const { css } = await postcss([autoprefixer]).process(source);
                    return css;
                },
            }),
        ],
    })
    .then(() => console.log("⚡ Build complete! ⚡"))
    .catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

In the `app/assets/config/manifest.js` I have the following content:

```
// = link_tree ../images
// = link_tree ../scss .css
// = link_tree ../ts .js
// = link_tree ../builds
```

But I am using a different folder structure that is probably causing the issues. This is my folder structure for `.scss` and `.ts` files:

```
app/
└── assets/
    ├── scss/
    │   ├── math/
    │   │   └── calculate.scss
    │   └── app.scss
    └── ts/
        ├── math/
        │   └── calculate.ts
        └── app.ts
```

As you can see, under `assets` I have created the folders `scss` and `ts`, which makes more sense to me than putting the typescript in the javascript folder first. The problem is that when I use the include tag:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'math/calculate', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

The asset cannot be found, I think it is caused by the fact that it is still looking in the `assets/javascript` folder.

I can see in the `public/assets` that all my ts files are now .js files and all the .scss files are .css files, so ESBuild does his job, but the problem is in the including part I think. I get this error:

```
The asset "math/calculate.js" is not present in the asset pipeline.
```

Can someone help me fix this, I hope I can keep my folder structure like it is now!?

Comment: How can I change directory of the compiled assets. In my esbuild.js I have set `outdir`, but that is going into `dist`, which only contains a `app.js` and a `app.cs`? `dist` contains 2 files which are the total of all compiled files, but that doesn't allow me to include seperate scripts right?

Comment: like this I guess: `outdir: "app/assets/builds"`. because this is where rails is looking `= link_tree ../builds`. whatever files you compile can go into `javascript_include_tag`. if you want them separate, you have to compile them as a separate file

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. Like I said, the `outdir` contains 2 folders `scss` and `ts`. In each folder there is a `app.css` or `app.js`. Then when I try to import `math/calculate`, it doesn't exist. I can only import `ts/app`.....

Comment: I can get each file in the build folder, when I add each file to the `entryPoints` array in the `esbuild.js`, but that doesn't seem like a good solution right? That means that everytime I create a new typescript file, I have to manually add it to esbuild. I am hoping for something that just checks the entire folder for all ts files and compiles those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I have to mention that *rails* comes with tools to build javascript and css, we'll be doing our own set up, but these are still useful as a reference:
*https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails*
*https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails*

---

In *Rails 7* js, css, and any other local assets are served by [*sprockets*](https://github.com/rails/sprockets). For *sprockets* to find your assets they have to be in `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`; any directory under `app/assets/` will be automatically be part of asset paths:

```rb
>> Rails.application.config.assets.paths
=> ["/home/alex/code/SO/ts/app/assets/builds",
    "/home/alex/code/SO/ts/app/assets/config",
    "/home/alex/code/SO/ts/app/assets/scss",
    "/home/alex/code/SO/ts/app/assets/ts",
    ...
```

Most of the time an app would serve `application.js` and `application.css`. Any assets that go into `javascript_include_tag`, `stylesheet_link_tag` or anything else that needs to be served in the browser, also have to be declared for precompilation. For js and css these are the entrypoints, where you `@import` other files to be part of a bundle:

```py
# app/assets/config/manifest.js

//= link_tree ../builds
```

`app/assets/builds` directory is in asset paths and every file in that directory will be precompiled in production. Because *sprockets* works with `js` and `css`, there has to be an additional build step to compile `ts` => `js` and `scss` => `css`.

---

The asset source files can be anywhere and organized however you like, *rails* doesn't care about them, as long as compiled assets end up in `app/assets/builds`.

CSS:

```js
// esbuild.css.js

import esbuild from "esbuild";
import { sassPlugin } from "esbuild-sass-plugin";
import postcss from "postcss";
import autoprefixer from "autoprefixer";

const watch = process.argv.includes("--watch");

esbuild
  .build({

    // declare you entrypoint, where, I hope, you're importing all other styles.
    entryPoints: ["app/assets/scss/app.scss"],

    // spit out plain css into `builds`, so that sprockets can serve them.
    outdir: "app/assets/builds",

    // you'll want this running with --watch flag
    watch: watch,

    publicPath: "assets",
    bundle: true,
    metafile: true,
    plugins: [
      sassPlugin({
        async transform(source) {
          const { css } = await postcss([autoprefixer]).process(source);
          return css;
        },
      }),
    ],
  })
  .then(() => console.log("⚡ CSS build complete! ⚡"))
  .catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

JS:

```js
// esbuild.js

import esbuild from "esbuild";
import glob from "glob";

const watch = process.argv.includes("--watch");

esbuild
  .build({

    // you say you want every file compiled separately, best I could come up:
    entryPoints: glob.sync("app/assets/ts/**/*.ts"),

    // spit out plain js into `builds`
    outdir: "app/assets/builds",

    watch: watch,
    publicPath: "assets",
    bundle: true,
    metafile: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("⚡ JS build complete! ⚡"))
  .catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

*Rails* compiles js and css separately, and so can we. This also avoids nested `build/ts/` and `build/scss/` directories.

---

In case you don't have this:

```bash
# bin/dev

#!/usr/bin/env sh
if ! gem list foreman -i --silent; then
  echo "Installing foreman..."
  gem install foreman
fi
exec foreman start -f Procfile.dev "$@"
```

```rb
# Procfile.dev

web: bin/rails server
_js: yarn build --watch
css: yarn build:css --watch
```

Add build scripts:

```js
// package.json

{
...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node esbuild.js",
    "build:css": "node esbuild.css.js"
  }
}
```

I think this should be everything:

```bash
app/assets
├── builds               # <= this is the only directory "servable" by sprockets
├── config
│  └── manifest.js       # //= link_tree ../builds
├── scss
│  ├── app.scss          # @import "./math/calculate.scss"
│  └── math
│     └── calculate.scss
└── ts
   ├── app.ts            # no imports here? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
   └── math
      └── calculate.ts   # console.log("do the calc")
```

You can run `bin/dev` to start the server and start compiling `scss` and `ts`:

```bash
$ bin/dev
```

or run build scripts manually:

```bash
$ yarn build && yarn build:css
⚡ JS build complete! ⚡
⚡ CSS build complete! ⚡
```

And it compiles into *builds* directory:

```bash
app/assets/builds
├── app.css
├── app.js
└── math
   └── calculate.js
```

These ^ are the assets you can use in your layout:

```rb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "app", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "app", "math/calculate", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
```

Now, when you ask for `math/calculate`, *sprockets* will find it in `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` and it will check if it is declared for precompilation:

```rb
# NOTE: if it is, you get a digested url to that file
>> helper.asset_path("math/calculate.js")
=> "/assets/math/calculate-11273ac5ce5f76704d22644f4b03b94908a318451578f2d10a85847c0f7f2998.js"

# everything as expected here
>> puts URI.open(helper.asset_url("math/calculate.js", host: "http://localhost:5555")).read
(() => {
  // app/assets/ts/math/calculate.ts
  console.log("do the calc");
})();
```

---

Hook your custom build scripts into a few *rails* tasks, like `assets:precompile` so that everything gets built automatically when deploying:
*https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails/blob/v1.1.1/lib/tasks/jsbundling/build.rake*

```rb
# lib/tasks/build.rake

namespace :ts_scss do
  desc "Build your TS & SCSS bundle"
  task :build do
    # put your build commands here VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
    unless system "yarn install && yarn build && yarn build:css"
      raise "Command build failed, ensure yarn is installed"
    end
  end
end

if Rake::Task.task_defined?("assets:precompile")
  Rake::Task["assets:precompile"].enhance(["ts_scss:build"])
end

if Rake::Task.task_defined?("test:prepare")
  Rake::Task["test:prepare"].enhance(["ts_scss:build"])
elsif Rake::Task.task_defined?("spec:prepare")
  Rake::Task["spec:prepare"].enhance(["ts_scss:build"])
elsif Rake::Task.task_defined?("db:test:prepare")
  Rake::Task["db:test:prepare"].enhance(["ts_scss:build"])
end
```

**OMG!** Do not precompile assets in development! I don't know where people got that idea. You'll be serving assets from `public/assets` and they will not update automatically. If you did, just undo it:

```bash
bin/rails assets:clobber
```

---

Long story short:

```rb
app/assets/ts/app.ts    # compile to `js` with esbuild
  V                     # output into builds
app/assets/builds       # is in `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`
  V                     # is in `manifest.js` (//=link_tree ../builds)
javascript_include_tag("app")
  V
asset_path("app.js")    # served by `sprockets`
  V                     # or by something else in production (thats why we precompile)
Browser!
```

Comment: I still have one question about this. I included everything in my app.scss, so after it is compiled, I have a app.css with all css from all imports. This is being imported in my `application.html.erb`, but I always thought I should split up the javascript logic and css, so I only include it on pages where I need it. Doesn't this impact performance of the app. From your story, I think you thought it was weird that I wanted every js file seperate and not bundled, because I thought I should include a specific file only when the page needs it. Does this bundled stuff make your app perform slower?

Comment: Also, you said that I should never precompile assets in development, but if I don't I get an error that the resource, I am trying to include does not exist? How does that work?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk you can absolutely have multiple bundles, but doing every file separate, feels like a lot of manual work. also depends on the size of your app. esbuild, has `splitting` you might want to look into that. you can use cdn for external packages to offload some of the work.

Comment: you have to run the build scripts first and you should always use `bin/dev` which does all that for you. there is a bit of a mix up with naming: compiling `ts`=>`js`, always do that. precompiling is a sprockets term when you run `bin/rails assets:precompile` for deployment. when you do precompile in development it breaks asset reloading.

Comment: Okay thank you for explaining. I have now setup the ESBuild watcher. So I will never run `rails assets:precompile` in development, but I can run npm run watch for both TS and SCSS compilation without compiling to the `public` folder then, right?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk you got it. assets only go into public folder in production.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250713/discussion-between-a-vreeswijk-and-alex).